# Remove JSON objects from a large file

Tags: c#, json

---

I have a JSON file that I want to be able to amend in C#. I want to be able to delete a set of data.

```
[
{
    "ID": "ID0000001",
    "Name": "ABCD",
    "Std": "4"
},
{
    "ID": "ID5335355",
    "Name": "JKLM",
    "Std": "6"
},
{
    "ID": "ID53534535",
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Std": "12"
}
]
```

---

how to remove the one id,name and std. like this :

```
{
    "ID": "ID0000001",
    "Name": "ABCD",
    "Std": "4"
}
```

---

after delete this json file like this :

```
[    
{
    "ID": "ID5335355",
    "Name": "JKLM",
    "Std": "6"
},
{
    "ID": "ID53534535",
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Std": "12"
}
]
```

---

I will need to perform one by one delete operations on the Json file. The Json file could contain thousands of results and I really need the most performant way possible.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to convert JSON to list of objects, remove and serialize it back to JSON

Comment: Can these one-by-one operations be batched, or do they have to be performed in isolation?

Comment: Maybe you should look into BSON format. It will be quicker to parse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Json.NET` to deserialize the string into objects. Then use `Linq` to select the wanted items, and then use `Json.NET` again to get the `JSON` string.

```
public class Item
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int Std {get; set;}
}

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(JsonString);

var newJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items.Where(i => i.ID != "ID0000001"));
```

Comment: I am not able to understand where is the code for deletion, please suggest.

Comment: items.Where(i => i.ID != "ID0000001") returns all Items **except** for the one with the id of  "ID0000001".