# Delete JSON Data inside Property based on ID in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a requirement to delete the data inside JSON file. I have tried so many way but it is not deleting the data. I have also tried this example.

[Remove JSON objects from a large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000782/remove-json-objects-from-a-large-file/31001242?noredirect=1#comment75334172_31001242)

But in above example they are passing a jsonstring but I have a jobject type of data.

My JSON File is as following.

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "Pankaj Kumar",
  "address": {
    "street": "El Camino Real",
    "city": "San Jose",
    "zipcode": 95014
  },
  "experiences": [
    {
      "companyid": 1,
      "companyname": "abc1"
    },
    {
      "companyid": 20,
      "companyname": "Genpact Headstrong"
    },
    {
      "companyid": 71,
      "companyname": "new company"
    },
    {
      "companyid": 77,
      "companyname": "Mind Tree LTD"
    },
    {
      "companyid": 89,
      "companyname": "TCS"
    },
    {
      "companyid": 22,
      "companyname": "Hello World LTD"
    }
  ],
  "phoneNumber": 9988664422,
  "role": "Developer"
}
```

I want to delete company based on companyid.

I have tried following code to delete based on company id.

```
private void DeleteCompany() {
 var json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
 try {
  var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
  JArray experiencesArrary = (JArray) jObject["experiences"];
  Console.Write("Enter Company ID to Delete Company : ");
  var companyId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  if (companyId > 0) {
   var companyName = string.Empty;

   foreach(var company in experiencesArrary.Where(obj => obj["companyid"].Value < int > () == companyId)) {
    companyName = Convert.ToString(company["companyname"]);
   }

   var companyToDeleted = "{ 'id': " + companyId + ", 'companyname': '" + companyName + "'}";
   experiencesArrary.Remove(companyToDeleted);

   jObject["experiences"] = experiencesArrary;
   string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
   File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, output);
  } else {
   Console.Write("Invalid Company ID, Try Again!");
   UpdateCompany();
  }
 } catch (Exception) {

  throw;
 }
}
```

Please suggest or modify my code which delete the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for creating deleteObject like you are doing, you are very close to solution.You can simply find your object like this and remove.

```
var companyToDeleted = experiencesArrary.Where(obj => obj["companyid"].Value<int>() == companyId).ToList();

foreach (var item in companyToDeleted)
{
   experiencesArrary.Remove(item);
}
```

**Update**

```
var companyToDeleted = experiencesArrary.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj["companyid"].Value<int>() == companyId);

experiencesArrary.Remove(companyToDeleted);
```

Comment: It is not working, please check my code. i need to delete one object from full json array.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Am I missing something? You want to remove one company from your experiences array. If so this code should work.

Comment: You can test the code from here http://csharppad.com/gist/fc71fbf7c5553db33974a778a182893d